# How to generate an image from OSM on command line?

Tags: openstreetmap, linux, svg

Is there a GNU/Linux command line tool that allows to generate an image file from OSM, preferably as an SVG?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a dedicated page for OSM SVG exporting: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/SVG

One way to do this through command line would be to use Maperitive - here's a [tutorial on how to generate SVG](http://gis.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/maperitive-tutorial-generating-osm-map-for-adobe-illustrator-in-seven-easy-steps/). You can simply write all the commands mentioned in the tutorial into a text file and run Maperitive with the file specified in the [command line](http://maperitive.net/docs/manual/Command_Line.html). Here are some user-written instructions on how to [install Maperitive on Linux](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive#Ubuntu_10.04).

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of Maperitive).

Answer (score 4):

A Perl script called [Geo-OSM-Tiles-0.02](http://search.cpan.org/~rotkraut/Geo-OSM-Tiles-0.02/downloadosmtiles.pl) might just do the job. From the module's description:

```
This script downloads all map tiles from an OpenStreetMap tile server for some geographic
region in a range of zoom levels. The PNG images of the tiles are stored in a directory   
tree that mirrors the paths from the server. 

A bounding box of geographic coordinates and a range of zoom levels must be selected 
by command line options.
```

Output's PNGs though.